# Where is `class vector` implemented in libcxx?

Tags: c++, libc++

I would like to find the implementation of `class vector` in libcxx. However, in the header file `vector` of libcxx, https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/libcxx/include/vector , there is only `class vector` defined in comment region, instead of in source region.

Where is `class vector` really defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's right there, around [line 472](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/96100f15082679b2c75c7744b8eb4fc87fcf71f5/libcxx/include/vector#L472):

```
template <class _Tp, class _Allocator /* = allocator<_Tp> */>
class _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS vector
    : private __vector_base<_Tp, _Allocator>
{
    . . .
```

Comment: I didn't notice the `_LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS` until you pointed out.